# Search Row/Record From Android Room database by search view widget, But When I click after search , It's provide incorrect Position

Tags: android, android-studio

It's Work fine, but when I search something by search view, It's Showing results by search keyword, works fine. when I click the search result's then it's showing incorrect position. Any solution? I am trying this thing since a week.

Main Activity

```
  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        final List<ModelClass>filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (query!=null){
                getItemFromDb(query);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText!=null){
                getItemFromDb(newText);
            }else {
                //when search view is empty then set all data to the adapter class
                noteAdapter.setList(listData);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



    private void getItemFromDb(String query){
    String searchText = "%"+query+"%";
    final List<ModelClass>myList = new ArrayList<>(); //now it is empty
    LiveData<List<ModelClass>>listLiveData = viewModel.getSearchData(searchText);

    listLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<List<ModelClass>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<ModelClass> modelClasses) {
            myList.addAll(modelClasses);
            noteAdapter.setList(myList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);

        }
    });
}
```

Dao interface

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

@Insert
void insert(ModelClass modelClass);

@Delete
void delete(ModelClass modelClass);

@Update
void update(ModelClass modelClass);

@Query("SELECT * FROM myNewNote")
LiveData<List<ModelClass>>getAllNote();



@Query("SELECT * FROM myNewNote WHERE title LIKE ( :searchQuery) ORDER BY id")
LiveData<List<ModelClass>> getSearchDatabase(final String searchQuery);
```

Comment: Can you share screenshots of what exactly is the issue that you are getting. Also why have you put recyclerview.setAdapter() inside onChanged of livedata observe. Just move this to where you are creating adapter object somewhere in onCreate of activity. This might fix your issue

Comment: not working your solution, can I send you a video, this is a screen recorder.

Answer (score 1):

**initially you to check record from Db by Log**`

```
    listLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<List<ModelClass>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<ModelClass> modelClasses) {
        myList.addAll(modelClasses);
        noteAdapter.setList(myList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);

        Log.e("List = ", list.toString())



    }
});`
```

**implement these line of code in adapter**

```
fun getNoteAt(position: Int) = items[position]

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CharacterViewHolder, position: Int) =
    holder.bind(items[position])
```